# Multiple schools on moodle

Tags: php, moodle

I'm trying to setup multiple school in a single moodle installation

I know Moodle does not supports it

Comment: please to read http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx and try asking your question again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm about to try using the same code base installation to run multiple moodle sites each with a different db. This is how I intend to do so hope it helps.

Point multiple domains to the same folder.

Edit my config file so that it has a list of incoming domains then changes the database and the datadir depending on the incoming name map.

pseudo code below

```
$domains = ('somedomain' => (object) array('dbname' => 'somedb', 'dbpass' => 'somedbpass', 'datadir' => 'somepath');

$domaincfg = $domains[$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']];

// set the appropriate variables on the cfg dynamically including the wwwroot
$CFG->wwwroot = http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
etc.
```

If you are trying to partition user's from each other within the same database of courses you should look into course groups using separate mode. That is the closest you will get without doing a bunch of coding. You can even assign each user a specific theme so the site will look totally different but this is a manual process so it is a pain.

Answer (score 5):

Try IOMAD (http://www.iomad.org/) for Moodle. It allows you to have Multiple Schools within the same Moodle, you can create schools (they call it companies), departments within a school, assign users to schools and every school can have their own logo, courses and users.

It has version from 2.5 until 3.0, you can download the code for free here: https://github.com/iomad/iomad

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. you can give answer with some explanation. but here question is also not clear.and the answer which you gave can be in comment also.

Comment: I didn't have enough reputation to comment some minutes ago, reason why I had to add a new comment. I don't see reason to vote negative. The question is clear from my point of view. I have had several clients asking for the same. ELIS and IOMAD are tools for Moodle and these plugins allow you to create multiple schools (or tenants) on a single Moodle instance.

Answer (score 1):

[Moodle Instance Management](https://docs.moodle.org/38/en/Moodle_Instance_Management)
This might help. You will have to install the [VMoodle](https://moodle.org/plugins/block_vmoodle) block and add it to a page to access the settings of this plugin.
And there is also a discussion about multi tenancy in the [moodle forum](https://moodle.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=13211)